his error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
pip install validate email
Collecting validate
Using cached validate-1.0.1.tar.gz (32 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [23 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\beras.virtualenvs\django-GatewayMonitoring-website-_fBZbT0M\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\beras.virtualenvs\django-GatewayMonitoring-website-_fBZbT0M\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\beras.virtualenvs\django-GatewayMonitoring-website-_fBZbT0M\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\beras\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g_ifnqns\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325,
in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\beras\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g_ifnqns\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295,
in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\beras\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g_ifnqns\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487,
in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "C:\Users\beras\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g_ifnqns\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311,
in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 13, in 
File "C:\Users\beras\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6bmuq9nw\validate_74389ea5db364065a48c1b8f2d9e1ca1\configobj.py", line 1632
except Exception, e:
^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not
a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.
I'm currently working in a django project, and tried to install "validate email". I'm unable to install it.

That "validate" package you're trying to install was last updated in 2010 and seems unmaintained. Are you sure you actually want to use that package?
